# How do you tally up values for elements within an array based on a recurring property of an element in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, dynamic, foreach

I am trying to work with a large array. Each element within the array is taken from a line of a SQL table and has multiple objects. Each line from the SQL table is a time entry, and included a User ID, a start time, and an end time. I am trying to see if in a given data set (which will be one day’s worth of data) a particular User ID has logged at least 8 hours total.

For example, a small section of the array (named $Array) might look like this:

```
UserID: 1
StartTime: 8:00 AM
EndTime: 10:00 AM 

UserID: 2
StartTime: 8:00 AM
EndTime: 10:30 AM 

UserID: 3
StartTime: 9:00 AM
EndTime: 10:00 AM 

UserID: 1
StartTime: 10:00 AM
EndTime: 01:00 PM 

UserID: 3
StartTime: 10:00 AM
EndTime: 04:00 PM
```

And so on. How can I loop through each element and tally up the allocated time for each the user ID?

Calculating the total time per entry is easy enough:

```
#Calculate entry length
ForEach ($element in $array)
{
$EntryStart = $element.StartTime
$EntryEnd = $element.EndTime
$EntryLength = $EntryEnd-$EntryStart
}
```

From this, I can successfully calculate the time of the entry via $EntryLength. I am struggling to add the value of $EntryLength to an overall timekeeping variable based on the UserID. How can I dynamically change the name of the timekeeping variable I am adding the $entrylength value to within each loop?

So far, I have tried this without success.

```
#Find all User IDs in recent Entries
ForEach ($Element in $Array)
{
$UserID = $Element.UserID
$userIDs += "$UserID"
}

#Remove Duplcate IDs from array
$UniqueUserIDs = $userIDs | select -Unique

#Create unique variable for each user ID
ForEach ($UniqueUserID in $UniqueUserIDs)
{
New-Variable = -Name "TimeFrom$UniqueUserID"
}
```

This last part produces variables from each user ID, such as

```
$TimeFrom1
$TImeFrom2
$Timefrom3
```

I tried dynamically creating the text  which matches the name of the global timekeeping variable (e.g. 'TimeFrom1')  within the loop, and using that to add each element's $EntryLength, but this isn't working.

```
#Add time to timekeeping variables
ForEach ($element in $array)
{
$UserID = $element.UserID
$EntryStart = $element.Starttime
$EntryEnd = $element.Endtime
$EntryLength = $EntryEnd-$EntryStart
$LoopTimeKeepingVariable = "TimeFrom$userID"
$"$LoopTimeKeepingVariable" += $EntryLength
}
```

Is there a better way to tally up all of the time for each user ID?

Here is all of the code in one go in case that is helpful:

```
#Find all User IDs in recent Entries
ForEach ($Element in $Array)
{
$UserID = $Element.UserID
$userIDs += "$UserID"
}

#Remove Duplicate IDs from array
$UniqueUserIDs = $userIDs | select -Unique

#Create unique variable for each user ID
ForEach ($UniqueUserID in $UniqueUserIDs)
{
New-Variable = -Name "TimeFrom$UniqueUserID"
}

#Add time to timekeeping variables
ForEach ($element in $array)
{
$UserID = $element.UserID
$EntryStart = $element.StartTime
$EntryEnd = $element.EndTime
$EntryLength = $EntryEnd-$EntryStart
$LoopTimeKeepingVariable = "TimeFrom$userID"
$"$LoopTimeKeepingVariable" += $EntryLength
}
```

I am in no way set on using unique variables to achieve this task, and graciously welcome any alternative methods to achieve the intended purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, which will output the `UserID` values with 8 or more total hours:

```
$array | Group-Object UserID | Foreach-Object {
    $TimeSpans = $_.Group | Foreach-Object { New-TimeSpan $_.StartTime $_.EndTime }
    if ([System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([double[]]$TimeSpans.TotalHours) -ge 8) {
        $_.Name
    }
}
```

If you only need to know the `UserID` value if one specific time span is 8 hours or more, you can simply modify the code above to not perform a sum:

```
$array | Group-Object UserID | Foreach-Object {
    $TimeSpans = $_.Group | Foreach-Object { New-TimeSpan $_.StartTime $_.EndTime }
    if ($TimeSpans.TotalHours -ge 8) {
        $_.Name
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: How To Detect 0 Time For User Not in the Table**

```
$UserIDs = 1,2,3,4,5,6
$AllUsers = $array + ($UserIDs | Where {$_ -notin $array.UserID} | Foreach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{UserID = $_; StartTime = 0; EndTime = 0}
})
$AllUsers | Group-Object UserID | Foreach-Object {
    $TimeSpans = $_.Group | Foreach-Object { New-TimeSpan $_.StartTime $_.EndTime }
    if ($TimeSpans.TotalHours -lt 8) {
        $_.Name
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

`$TimeSpans` will contain every time span for the current `UserID` value. At this point, you can choose to sum all the `TotalHours` values for that `UserID` or use a comparison operator `-ge` (greater than or equal to) to determine if any time span is 8 or more hours.

Using [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) on the `UserID` property will group all objects with matching `UserID` values into one object. The `Name` property of that grouping will contain the `UserID` grouped value. The `Group` property will contain a collection of the objects with matching `UserID` values.

[New-TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan?view=powershell-7) creates a time span between start and end times. The returned object contains time-related properties including `TotalHours`.

Using LINQ's `Sum()` method, we can easily sum an array of equal numeric types.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Here is a follow up question. Say I have another userID, UserID 4. But UserID 4 did not enter any entries for a particular day.

If I have an array of UserIDs, $UserIDs = @("1","2","3","4"), how could I modify the above script to catch UserID 4 as having less than 8 hours logged if there are no entries for UserID4 in $array?

Comment: @AlexanderTheGreat I added an edit that can handle that situation.

Comment: Thank you! I have learned a lot from this. The Group-Object feature is really powerful!

Comment: I also had to change the 'Hours' method to 'TotalHours' in the comparison operator portion to get the total time for entries that are, x hours an y minutes long. Just adding this for any future souls who come across this post.